# Understanding RNN input for word prediction

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, prediction, recurrent-neural-network

While taking an input for a word prediction model in rnn tensorflow,
why do we need a 3d tensor?
Please look at the code below.
Why do we need that extra `1` here?

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input, 1])
```

Comment: Shouldn't the shape be: `[batch_size, timesteps, num_inputs]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emm, I guess you are using simple predict model, maybe just for demonstrate. We tried to use RNN to predict model with an basic idea that each word in a sentence will be affected by the former or the latter words(that's what we called context), so we use the sequential inputs of words in a sentence to represent words appear one by one with the time passes.
So we need a Tensor with a shape `[batch_size, words_counts, words_represent]`, and in your situation, `words_counts` is `n_input` represents `time steps`, and the word represent tensor `words_represent` is shape `(1, )` tuple.
**BUT**, in real practice, we not just transfer each word into an `(1, )` tuple, we may use word embedding to create a meaningful and useful tensor represent of a word. So maybe i guess that you have tried a simple demo or may i making mistakes.